# Is it a bad practice to have the same class name in two different components when the CSS is scoped?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this snippet of code in 2 different components:

```
<div class="justify-center summoner-runes">
    <img class='summoner-rune-icon' :src="'https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/' + $store.getters.findSummonerRune(participant.stats.perk0).icon" alt="">
    <img class='summoner-rune-icon absolute-rune' :src="'https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/' + $store.getters.findSummonerRune(participant.stats.perkSubStyle).icon" alt="">
</div>
```

In component one, I want the summoner-rune-icon class to have width of 40px, however, in component two I want it to have width of 20px. Because the CSS on both components is scoped, I don't think the rules will conflict with each other, however, I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of scoped classes that they wont clash, that way you can encapsulate each components styling separately

Comment: Yep as Michael commented, that is the whole point.  So no it is not bad practice it.

Comment: Great, this is what I needed to know. Thanks!